# Login to website using android account

Tags: android, node.js, passport.js, google-oauth

I am building a responsive web application. It uses oauth login with google and it is working just fine (nodejs with passportjs).

When surfing the site from android phone and pressing 'login' I am getting the google login page, just as when using a desktop.

Is it possible to use the google account from Android instead of forcing the user to enter his credentials?

Comment: read this article https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp

Comment: I didn't try it just yet. But it looks just the same to me. The user is redirected to google login page. I want it to work together with the Android identity. I am not sure if this is even possible.  S

Comment: your application is independent of the android system, hence when running it in the android browser, its not different like you moved from one computer to another, so you will still be required to login[auth]

Comment: I was afraid  that might be the case. So basically what I want does not exist :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Integrate the google login** in your website and i suppose it takes logged in chrome account and helps you log in! You can see it working :

Surf the **

> stackoverflow

** website from your mobile, try log in , you will be provided with a button google login and after click it if the user is logged in to his android phone using the google account you will be logged in *automagically*(you must be registered to the stackoverflow website with same account and in your case the user must be signed in using *same account*

on your website)

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Could be it a matter of versions? I am using LG mini G2, running Android 4.4.2 and latest chrome. When going to stackoverflow.com and clicking 'Log in'  I am being redirected to accounts.google.com and being asked to enter my email.

Comment: Ok. I get it now. You first need to login to Chrome with the android account. I usually using the browser without login in. I guess that is good enough for me. I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 2):

In case you do not store a generated keys based on the user and service within a domain e.g. tt is not possible without user enter the credentials when using a webpage.

Comment: Could you please elaborate about the keys? How and where do you use them?

Comment: Here is some more links to help, but it could be it only apply to service accounts.
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this will not work for web application.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you are trying to do isn't possible, because if it was hypothetically I could login to your personal account from my desktop.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the answer. What  do you mean by login from the desktop? I obviously want the user to have some popup asking him permission to use the account.